# Using the same column for multiple mappings in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have run my own tests and don't believe this is possible but was hoping to get some confirmation.

I have two objects that are being persisted using hibernate, `Child` and `Parent`. A `Child` always has a reference to a single `Parent` and and `Parent` has a Set of `Child` Objects. On top of this a parent has a List of favorites which consists of Child objects.

This is mapped using the following HBM definitions:

```
<class name="Parent" table="parent">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>

  <set cascade="all,delete-orphan" inverse="true" name="children">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
  </set>

  <list cascade="none" name="favorites">
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
    <key>
      <column name="parent_id" not-null="false"/>
    </key>
    <index>
      <column name="fav_index"/>
    </index>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
  </list>
</class>

<class name="Child" table="child">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
  <many-to-one column="parent_id" name="parent" not-null="false"/>

</class>
```

The trouble I am having is with the column `parent_id` in the `child` table. It works fine when I persist Child objects that have references to a parent and when I persist Parent objects that have a list of favorites. However, when I try and remove a child from a parents list of favorites, the column `child.parent_id` gets set to null, even though I have not removed the Parent Object from the Child before it is persisted.

From my tests, I don't think there is anyway around this other than using a different column name for the favorites key column in the Parent mapping. It just seems a bit of a shame to do that since these two columns will always have the same value.

Does anyone if this is possible or will I have to use two columns?

Thanks

Comment: How is it supposed to know if a child is a favorite?  Just based on non-null index?  That is not supported, no

Comment: Why don't you just add a boolean favorite flag to the child entity? That way, the parent information is stored in one and only one column, and the favorite information is stored in one and only one column. getting the list of favorites would simply be a metter of filtering the collection of children to only retain those who are flagged as favorites.

Comment: @Affe - Yeah that makes sense, hibernate needs it own key column when own key column and is not able to only use the index column,

Comment: @JBNizet - I'm not sure that a boolean column will suffice in my problem. Its possible that there could be thousands of child entities related to a parent and very few of those would be favorites. I'm not sure the performance overhead of doing the filtering over all child objects would be justified when I could just add another column to the table.